# Wordpress on Apache: httpd can't write to vhost webroot

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-httpd, php

I have WordPress running in on an Apache vhost.
The vhost is configured to pass php requests to php-fpm.
I've created a php resource pool for the the vhost, and created a no-login linux user and corresponding group with the same name.

The user owns the vhosts filesystem. And in the pool definition, I've set the "user/group of processes" to the same name as the user/group that owns the docroot.

Perms are set as follows:  files to 664, directories to 775.

The owner of the webserver process is www-data - which is the default (I haven't touched any default apache configs. Just the vhost)

But apache is unable to write or delete files.

When I use the WordPress UI to install or delete plugins, the operations fail.
If I change the docroot user and group ownership to www-data:www-data, then the operations succeed.

But I want the directory to be owned by it's own user.

How do I keep the ownership of the filesystem in the hands of the unique user, but allow server process to read and write to the filesystem?

Comment: Have you tried to add the user's group to user `www-data`?

Comment: @Freddy do you mean "add the user to the group www-data"? If so, yes. The user is a member of the group www-data.

Comment: Argh, sorry for the confusion. I meant "add user www-data to the user's group" (if the files belong to the user).